# How do you change the settings of iopub_data_rate_limit = 10000000?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a for loop to process a large dataset in chunks. When I run my code I get the error message:

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

How do I change the settings of

```
iopub_data_rate_limit = 10000000
```

if I am using the Anaconda interface to open up a Jupyter Notebook rather then the command line?

Comment: Try edit it at ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

Comment: @chifulin, Thanks, where do I find this?

Comment: Here is [reference](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) @mkheifetz

Comment: hmm, not sure I fully follow. I looked at the link, I don't really understand where that location is. Is that just where My Documents are? Also, can I do it in a ipynb file instead of py? I don't think I have py